# Automatic Android UI test script generation

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, automated-tests

I know that XCode for iOS development has an automatic test script creation, as seen here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UIAutomation.html

I was hoping to find a similar tool for Android, one that I can press the buttons on an android application and a test script with the actions would be automatically created.

Any tools like that out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which you can use to create test cases and script either manually or using [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) or [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI).

There's also a *concertina mode* that instead of sending pseudo-random events like [monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html), analyzes the content of the screen and randomly selects a suitable event or action for the also randomly selected target, normally a View.

So, you don't even have to press the buttons on the UI.

Comment: How can I find more information regarding _concertina mode_?

Comment: This [article](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2015/08/culebra-concertina-mode.html) explains the basic of **concertina mode**. The [source code](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/concertina.py) will also give you some idea of the inferred responses to common cases and the places where you can extend it and support your own.